# Split and merge nested DataFrame in Python

Tags: pandas, merge, split

I have a dataframe, which has two columns. One of the columns is also another dataframe. It looks like below:

[image: sample]

I want to have a dataframe with 3 columns, containing "Date_Region", "transformed_weight" and "Barcode", which would replicate each "Date_Region" row times the length of its "Weight-Barcode" dataframe. The final dataframe should looks like below:

[image: final]

Comment: provide data in text, don't post images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do:

```
pd.concat(
    iter(final_df.apply(
        lambda row: row['Weights-Barcode'].assign(
            Date_Region=row['Date_Region'],
        ),
        axis=1,
    )),
    ignore_index=True,
)[['Date_Region', 'transformed_weight', 'Barcode']]
```

From the inside out:

- `final_df.apply(..., axis=1)` will call the lambda function on each row.
- The lambda function uses `assign()` to return the nested DataFrame from that row with an addition of the `Date_Region` column with the value from the outside.
- Calling `iter(...)` on the resulting series results in an iterable of the DataFrames already including the added column.
- Finally, using `pd.concat(...)` on that iterable to concatenate them all together. I'm using `ignore_index=True` here to just reindex everything again (it doesn't seem to me your index is meaninful, and not ignoring them means you'd end up with duplicates.)
- Finally, I'm reordering the columns, so the added `Date_Region` column becomes the leftmost one.